# Trouble passing multiple values from one page to another in URL

Tags: apex

I'm trying to send a value from one page to another, I've tried adding it to my URL.

```
{!my_val} //Value is a simple string

<apex:outputLink value="/apex/NewPage?id={the_account.id}_myValue{!my_val}">
    <div class="link_class">
        <strong>Link</strong>
    </div>
</apex:outputLink>
```

But I have an Id at the end of my url and when I add my value, I get the following error:

```
Id value is not valid for the standard controller
```

So I'm assuming the value is breaking the Id.

If I add it before my Id, Salesforce says it can't find my page, so it seems to be breaking my Url.

```
{!my_val}    

<apex:outputLink value="/apex/NewPage_myValue{!my_val}?id={the_account.id}">
    <div class="link_class">
        <strong>Link</strong>
    </div>
</apex:outputLink>
```

Is there any way to pass my value through in my url?

**UPDATE**

Adding an ampersand seems to do the trick... Page loads and my value is appended to my Url with no errors.

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/NewPage?id={the_account.id}&myValue{!my_val}">
    <div class="link_class">
        <strong>Link</strong>
    </div>
</apex:outputLink>
```

Would anyone be able to tell me if this an acceptable solution?

Or are ampersands supposed to be avoided in Urls?

Comment: Similar post which basically answers your question

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31494/setting-visualforce-page-url-parameters-within-standard-page-layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daft, I think you resolved your own question. When passing more than one varialbes in a url, you need to seperate them using ampersand (&).

single variable:
http://myapp.test.com?var1=1

2 variables:
http://myapp.test.com?var1=1&var2=2

Note that the url string should be encoded for the browser to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a **double quote** at the end of your url?

> apex:outputLink value="/apex/NewPage?id={the_account.id}**"**

Comment: Cheers, but that was just a copy and paste error while writing my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to put '**myValue=**'

> VF Page

```
 <apex:outputLink value="/apex/NewPage?id={the_account.id}&myValue={!my_val}">`enter preformatted text here`
        <div class="link_class">
            <strong>Link</strong>
        </div>
    </apex:outputLink>
```

> Apex Code :

```
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('myValue');
```

I think this might be useful for you if im wrong then please correct me.