# Can't get URL Parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my Page Layout I am using one section calling a Visualforce Page. In Inner Visualforce Page I am not getting the URL parameter. How to get the parameter?

For example:

> https://zoya.force.com/a0MQ0000005lvkaMAA?RUN=9

In Inner section of the Visualforce page, in the Apex class I am calling

```
Apexpages.currentpage.getParameter('RUN')
```

But I'm getting a NULL Value. How to get the URL parameter in Inner section of  Visualforce page.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what you've written to get this. I posted an answer before fully reading your question! I imagine this is more about where you're getting and setting the variable holding the parameter for `RUN`.

Comment: Does ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RUN') help you?

Comment: In inner section i am calling API to get the lineitems ,so here if they pass the run parameter i am redirecting to main url as return new pagereference('/'+id+'?run='+run);In the URL i am getting the run value as true but in the inner vf page

Comment: Post the current code you are using.

Comment: i am getting the null value and above calling webservice is intermediate pagenot related to innersection vfpage

Comment: I think the description is little bit unclear. Please confirm whether the following is correct. 

You have developed a VF page (let's say Page1). In the controller for Page1, you look for the "RUN" query string parameter in the url and do some action based on it. Now you have embedded Page1 as an inline VF page in a custom object's page layout and expecting to read the "RUN" parameter if you pass it to the standard URL like https://zoya.force.com/a0MQ0000005lvkaMAA?RUN=9. 

If the above is correct, I don't think you can pass parameter to the inline VF page like you're doing.

Comment: @Swetha Please post your code or this question will likely get voted for closure. Include the code for the controller if you're using a custom controller or controller extension. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From bob Buzzard:

> When your Visualforce page is rendered inside the standard record
>   view, it will be passed the id of the current record as a URL
>   parameter and that is all - you cannot add further parameters. Any
>   additional parameters that you add in a controller will not have any
>   effect as the controller chain (standard plus any extensions) is
>   already have been constructed and the standard controller has
>   retrieved the record it is managing, populating fields based on those
>   you have used in your page.

linked here: [Setting Visualforce Page url parameters within standard page layouts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31494/setting-visualforce-page-url-parameters-within-standard-page-layouts)

I have seen some comments about using document.referrer but the details were not laid out and I have not personally used it but it may be worth a shot.

The following illustrates :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   Id: {!$CurrentPage.Parameters.id}
   tmp: {!$CurrentPage.Parameters.tmp}
</apex:page>
```

Now, hit the page using the url: https://xxx.salesforce.com/apex/PAGENAME?id=ANACCID&tmp=abcd

you will see the output as expected with the value "abcd" after the `tmp`

Now, put the page inline with an account record.
Then open an account and add `?tmp=abcd` to the standard URL.

You will see that the `tmp` has no value after it.

The inline page is within an iFrame and thus its own URL